# How to Resize the toolbar according to the length of the title?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design, toolbar

According to the fragment in which I am setting the title of my Toolbar, but some titles are very long and the App puts three points:

[image]

What I want is to display the full title, not decrease the size of the letter, if not increase the size of the toolbar so that if the title does not reach in a line that is put in a second as if it were a wrapcontent.

How is it possible to do this?

My toolbar in XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/Toolbar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Setting the title via Java

```
((NavigationDrawerActivity) activity)
                .getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mytext);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a custom toolbar that tries to fit text as much as possible. You should set this custom Toolbar as action bar like this: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.

Here is my custom toolbar code:

MyToolbar.java:

```
package com.aminography.textapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class MyToolbar extends Toolbar {

    private AppCompatTextView mTitleTextView;

    public MyToolbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mTitleTextView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.toolbar_title_layout, this).findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        addView(mTitleTextView);
    }

    public MyToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mTitleTextView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.toolbar_title_layout, this).findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        addView(mTitleTextView);
    }

    public MyToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mTitleTextView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.toolbar_title_layout, this).findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        addView(mTitleTextView);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(int resId) {
        mTitleTextView.setText(resId);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitleTextView.setText(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitleTextColor(int color) {
        mTitleTextView.setTextColor(color);
    }

}
```

toolbar_title_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="0.5sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

</FrameLayout>
```